# NotImplementedError: Django doesn't provide a DB representation

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm

I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/user/change-password/
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
   return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
   return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/opt/project/views.py", line 227, in put
   request.user.set_password(password)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 480, in set_password
   raise NotImplementedError("Django doesn't provide a DB representation for User.")
NotImplementedError: Django doesn't provide a DB representation for User.
```

**My code in which is shown line 227:**

```
class ChangePasswordAPI(View):
    @staticmethod
    def put(request):
        data = request.read()
        payload = json.loads(data)
        password = payload['password']

        if not request.user:
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({
                    'success': False,
                    'error': 'user_not_exist'
                })
            )
        # the following line is 227
        request.user.set_password(password)
        request.user.save()

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'success': True,
            })
        )
```

Firstly, I thought that this was due to the fact that I didn't have Django updated, but now I have, and I receive the same error.

I've looked at some solutions that other users asked, but none applied in my case

Any help, please ?

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not request.user:
```

This if statement only checks if `request.user` is a truthy object, which it will always be. If a user is not authenticated, it is an `AnonymousUser` which does not have a database representation. `set_password()` and various other methods will raise a `NotImplementedError`.

To fix it, change the if statement to:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
```